# How to display an image on the NSWindow title bar that's half outside

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nswindow, titlebar

I have a custom `NSWindow` subclass - `INAppStoreWindow` ([github](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow)) with a custom title bar view - and I'd like to do something like this image:
[image]

As you can see the ribbon is not totally outside the title bar. It's like in the middle.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do may be to use a separate window for the badge. Make it a child window of the main window and it will stay on top and move with it. It would be borderless and largely transparent, etc.

It may be hard to keep the badge child window positioned correctly if the main window is resized horizontally, though. Or, rather, you can move the badge child window easily enough, but it may lag the resize.

Answer (score 0):

Your image must be drawn inside the area of a window. 
Even if that means parts of your window are transparent.

You can do this with all the common border less window stuff. Just have two views your use for your title bar area. One for the titlebar itself where the view content is clear or you could say the opaque content is not reaching the top of the view. 
In a sub view for your badge, draw whatever badge you like. Have your badge view extend to to top of your title bar view and overlap its transparent area.

You are likely to run into bad trade offs with how your window interacts and looks with the menu bar. As this is highly non standard and has UI problems that should be provided and addressed by Cocoa if anywhere, I recommend finding a different design. This will take alto of work to maintain and complete well. Custom, borderless windows are not hard to do, but they can be hard to do well. There are numerous subtleties of visual state change in sub views of NSWindow on OS X. Colors change based on key & main status of the window. It's free with standard windows and views. With custom stuff, you have to do a lot more.